# Exposure compensation on flash only works in manual mode, is this normal?

Tags: flash, sony, ttl, exposure-compensation, nissin

I just got a Nissin MF18 ring flash to stick on my Sony α7 III. I'm just wondering if how it behaves is normal or if there's a setting buried somewhere in the camera or flash that might change it. In TTL mode, there's a setting on the flash for EV (up to three stops each way) however in every mode on the camera but full manual the setting on the flash does nothing, the only way to change it is to adjust the flash exposure compensation on the camera (takes a bit more time than two big buttons on the flash ready to change it, plus it's not staring me right in the face on the flash's screen to remind me to change it back after I've used it) and I mostly shoot in aperture priority.

I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to Sony cameras (used Canon before) so as I said earlier I'm wondering if this is the expected behaviour and if I can change it? I'm running the latest firmware on both the camera and flash.